# Invoking AWS Lambda Asynchronously does not produce any logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I have followed instructions at: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-async.html#dlq in order to invoke my Lambda function asynchronously from command line:

```
aws lambda invoke --function-name MyLambda --invocation-type Event --payload '{private information}' response.json
{
    "StatusCode": 202
}
```

I do get `status code 202` returned but I do not see any logs regarding the execution.

How can I fix this?

**EDIT:**

Below is my execution policy in JSON format:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogStream"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:logs:xx-xxxx-x:xxxxxxxx:log-group:/aws/lambda/LambdaConfigService-dev*:*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:logs:xx-xxxx-x:xxxxxxxx:log-group:/aws/lambda/LambdaConfigService-dev*:*:*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Do you have appropriate `logs:*` permissions in the execution policy of your lambda function?

Comment: I've edited my question by putting in JSON execution policy. Please take a look.

Comment: Doe the log group already exist? You'd typically want logs:CreateLogGroup in your IAM policy, or simply apply AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason asynchronous logs needed around 5 mins to be created. I just left **CloudWatch Logs** page open for a while, refreshed and they've appeared (note that they did not appear on first couple of refresh actions once lambda function was executed). Apologize for the trouble, and many thanks.